# Strange comparisons in Python

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I was fooling around and stumbled on something I don't understand...

Question 1:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]

len(a) < b
```

The result is True, but is this actually comparing the *length* of the two lists?  It seems to be since this is also True...

```
a = [15,32,7]
len(a) < b
```

Question 2:

What happens when we try comparing integers with lists?  Why are these all True (I'm assuming there's a general explanation...)...

```
3 < b
20 < b
float('inf') < b
None < b
(lambda x: (x**x)**x) < b
```

...and these False?

```
'poo' < b
'0' < b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.x, items of dissimilar types which are not directly comparable are compared using the name of their types. So all integers are less than all lists, because `"int"` is less than `"list"`. For the same reason all `str`s are greater than all `int`s and `float`s.

This unintuitive behavior (which I assume was introduced so that items of like type sort together in a heterogeneous list) was removed in Python 3, which raises an exception for these comparisons.

Comment: Applied for `(2, ,3, 4) < [2, 3, 4]` also **?** I means this is = `"tuple" < "list"` = `False`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  So what about len(list1) < list2?  Is it actually comparing list lengths as it seems to be?

Comment: `len(list1)` is an integer, while `list2` is a list. The integer is always less than the list, as I stated. The lengths of the lists are not being compared.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: You might have caught my answer before I added "directly comparable" to it. Tuples and lists can be compared to each other because they are both sequences.

Comment: @kindall Yes but I just tried on my Python3.3 `(2, ,3, 4) < [2, 3, 4]`  gives me `TypeError: Unoderable Types tuple() < list()`.

Comment: kindall:  len([15, 32, 7, 45, 61]) < [1, 2, 3, 4] is False

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: kindall explicitly said that this behaviour was removed in Python 3, and that it raises an exception.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) on data types:

> Sequence objects may be compared to other objects with the same
>   sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the
>   first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the
>   outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are
>   compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

And

> Note that comparing objects of different types is legal. The outcome
>   is deterministic but arbitrary: the types are ordered by their name.
>   Thus, a list is always smaller than a string, a string is always
>   smaller than a tuple, etc. [1](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) Mixed numeric types are compared
>   according to their numeric value, so 0 equals 0.0, etc.

And, notably,

> **Footnotes** [1](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) The rules for comparing objects of different types
>   should not be relied upon; they may change in a future version of the
>   language.

Comment: Thanks, the bit about sequence objects was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a good job explaining what is happening, but the right way to compare the lengths is

```
len(a) < len(b)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP had trouble comparing lengths.  He wanted an explanation on why he was seeing the behavior he witnessed.  This answer, while correct, is not really targeted to the OP's needs.

Comment: Thats pretty much what I thought too, except this line "but is this actually comparing the length of the two lists". So I thought I'd throw it out there just in case.